# Proper way to submit data using GCD

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming, grand-central-dispatch

In my iOS application i have text data and bunch of images that i am submitting.I have created a manager class which is a singleton class.It has two separate method one for textual data submission and one for image submission.

So first I submit text data and on successful submission alert pops up and on click of alert view I pop the view controller and called image submission method using GCD,s **dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue())** method.So my question is as I am popping the view controller from navigation stack will this image submission method will work as the manager class is singleton or with view contoller the singleton object is also going to vanish.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question... singleton objects don't just 'vanish', they'll stay loaded as they have a strong static reference to the singleton object from within the singleton class (i.e they keep themselves always loaded). This is of course unless you manually set that reference to `nil`.

Comment: My question was if pop out the view controller the reference of that view controller become nil, so will it still execute image submission method.

Comment: Yes. GCD will retain the block until it has finished executing.

Comment: @originaluser2 your help is highly appriciated.